# Including Database Generated Pages in Site Search

Tags: custom-field, search

Our library uses a separate little php/mysql app and wordpress template pages to display lists of resources for users.

The resources are not included in site search, of course, since the pages are generated on the fly.  Lookup begins at a top level page with a search, alphabetical and subject browses.  Users can enter the resource name or drill down through the browse screens.  See libtest.drake.edu/find/article-databases

We would like to let users locate the resources via the site search.  The resources are in a database that exists outside the wordpress installation and tables.

At a minimum, we would like to take people to the top level (resource lookup page).  In the best scenario, we would like to take people to the actual resource listing itself.

What would be the best method to do accomplish this, preferably without extensive php coding (since we no longer have a developer)?  Are there plugins that could give us this functionality?